# Parse xml in jquery and store the xml element in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following xml structure:

```
 //xml
<ArrayofTech>
 <TechJobs>a</TechJobs>
 <TechJobs>b</TechJobs>
</ArrayofTech>
```

I would like to store in array the above TechJobs nodes xml like: Array.push(Techjobs). I have to store each TechJobs node into an array. How to parse this xml .The Code which i have tried is shown below:

```
$(xml).find("TechJobs").each(function () {
array.push($(this));
}
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Show us your full code, or make an online demo like on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use **.outerHTML** like,

```
var xml = "<ArrayofTech> <TechJobs>a</TechJobs> <TechJobs>b</TechJobs></ArrayofTech>";
var array = $(xml).find("TechJobs").map(function() {
    return this.outerHTML; // to get the techjob
}).get();
console.log(array);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/7pgmT/)

Answer (score 1):

Using [.get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/) alongside [.map](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to transform the data, should return you the array:

```
var array = $(xml).find("TechJobs").map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

If you want the XML, just use `.get` and leave out the mapping:

```
var array = $(xml).find("TechJobs").get();
```

[<kbd>jsFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/X3GE8/)

Comment: @RGraham I want the complete xml node ie TechJobs xml as a string not just the values.

Comment: @user3393032 Even easier, just remove the `.map` function

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/)** here:

```
var arr = $(xml).find("TechJobs").map(function() {
    return $(this).html();
}).get();
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vBEG4/)**